# Math.min.apply returns 0

Tags: jquery

There is five classes "price". The function takes the min number from the class and add it to the "price-box". Every thing works fine exept, when one of the class is empty - the script returs 0. 
How to fix it?

```
<div id="price-box"></div>

<table id="table-prices">
 <tr>
    <td>Ткань</td>
    <td>Цена (грн)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td class="priсe">1496</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td class="priсe">4496</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td class="priсe">2496</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td class="priсe">5296</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td class="prise">5696</td>
 </tr>
```

```
var array = [];
$('.priсe').each(function(){
    array.push(+$(this).text());
});
console.log(array);
var maximum = Math.min.apply(null,array);
$('#price-box').text(maximum + " грн");
```

Comment: None of your prices is empty. BTW, you misspelled it `prise` in the last one.

Comment: `maximum = Math.min...` hrm..

Comment: sorry my english, is not so good(
Сorrected it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking for an empty value:

```
$('.prise').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).text())!='')array.push(+$(this).text());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aF6Jr/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

you can eliminate empty rows by using `empty` selector.

```
$('.prise').not(':empty')each(function(){
 // rest of the function
});
```

as suggested, you can shorten it a bit like this:

```
$('.prise:not(:empty)') each(function () {
    // rest of the function
});
```

Comment: You can also do this without the seperate `.not()` call: `.prise:not(:empty)`